# Flutter - Dividir Sting

Tags: flutter

Bom dia, sou iniciante no flutter e tenho essa tela de login logo abaixo na imagem.
como podem observar tem uma **String** que seria o numero de serie do aparelho que ocupou todo meu espaço da tela **"D121273B-5B..."** .

**Minha dúvida:**
Como eu limito essa string na tela por exemplo a cada 16 caracteres ele pula linha \n qual melhor forma ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]